# How to change IPv4 Address on Public Wi-Fi?

Tags: windows-10, router, ipv4

I have two computers running Windows 10 that are connected to my Hotel's Wi-Fi. I am working on a project that requires both computers to be connected to the same Hotel router, i.e. the "host" part of their IPv4 Address is the same. If one computer has the IPv4 address `172.40.4.15` is it possible to force my other computer to connect to the same router? So that its IPv4 address is `172.40.4.xx`. Trial and error solutions are acceptable, e.g. connecting to random routers until both computers are on the same router. I can't seem to change the router at all, though.

Comment: If the router has DHCP enable you will be unable to control which IP address you are assigned.  Why don't you simply connect both devices to the router?  Unless the access point requires a username and password it's unlikely going to reject a second device.

Comment: DHCP is enabled. By connect both devices to the router, do you mean with an Ethernet cord? My Hotel room does not have Ethernet ports. The Wi-Fi login works by connecting and then redirecting you to a Hotel login page where you sign in with your name and room number.

Comment: You indicated you are connecting to the an WiFi access point.  An Ethernet connection cannot be used in the case you describe in your question.  It sounds like you are going to be unable to connect two devices to the access point in question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming these computers are not next to each other so they are connecting to different Wifi networks or hotspots.

> the "host" part of their IPv4 Address is the same.

The way to make this happen over two distinct networks you don't control--such as public Wifi or a cellular hotspot--is to use a VPN - as in a VPN that provides a virtual network adapter.

Once both devices are connected to the same VPN, you'll be on the same network.  There could be some limitations depending on what you are trying to do and the type of VPN you use.

A service like Hamachi might work.

There are ways to do this yourself if you want to get into setting up a dynamic DNS and a VPN server like OpenVPN, but it can be very involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an IP scan using [Advanced IP Scanner](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/news/index.php?ID=7946). It is free and safe. I use it all the time.

Configure it to scan the network computer 1 is on-> find an available IP address-> configure computer 2 to use the available address, subnet mask and default gateway. That will put both computers on the same network.

There MAY be some restrictions that will not allow you to scan the network, but I would give it a try